# splice not working when used inside for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert the name based on the position to the list.
but the splice is not working properly.

the list expected result should be = [
"x",
"x",
"tester2",
"tester1",
"tester1",
"tester2",
"x",
"tester2",
"tester1",
"x",
"x",
"x",
"x",
"x",
"x",
"x",
"tester1",
"tester2"
]

```js
var list = ['x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'];
var data = [{name:'tester1',position:'4,5,9,last'},{name:'tester2',position:'3,5,8,last'}]

 

for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  var position = data[i].position.split(",");
  var name = data[i].name;
  for (var x=0; x<position.length; x++){
    if(!isNaN(position[x])){
      position[x] -= 1;
      list.splice(position[x], 0, name);
    }else{
      list.splice(list.length, 0, name);
    }
  }
}

console.log('list',list)
```

Comment: have u tried ` list.splice(parseInt(position[x]), 0, name);` ?

Comment: To be honest I don't really get what you are trying to do. The `position.length` updates every time you add something, so the positions from the data objects are obsolete as soon as you add the first element. What exactly are you trying to archive?

Comment: when you splice, the array gets shorter, and you skip an element

Comment: After the first iteration the array has changed so successive `position` values aren't accurate in relation to the original array

Comment: Your indexes are going to be constantly changing inside the loop.  eg.  When you add the first tester1 as position 4, what was at position 5 will become 6,  8 will become 9 etc.

Comment: I'm trying to insert the name to the list array based on the position that is given and it will duplicate if they have both the same position

Answer (score 0):

As @Keith pointed out in a comment, "your indexes are going to be constantly changing inside the loop". Every time you insert a `name` into `list` at a given index, say `k`, it will increase the index of those items which had an original index larger than or equal to `k`, while the `position` values refer to the original index of these elements.

This problem can be solved by keeping the original index somehow, for example by using a temporary list of lists (`list2`), and flattening it after the insertions are finished:

```js
let list = ['x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'];
const data = [{name:'tester1',position:'4,5,9,last'},{name:'tester2',position:'3,5,8,last'}];

const list2 = list.map(item => [item]);
list2.push([]); // for last

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const position = data[i].position.split(",");
  const name = data[i].name;
  for (let x = 0; x < position.length; x++){
    if(!isNaN(position[x])) {
      list2[position[x] - 1].push(name);
    } else {
      list2[list2.length - 1].push(name);
    }
  }
}

list = list2.flat();
console.log('list', list);
```

Comment: thank you but this does not work the name are added correctly based on the position